# Работа с кэшем Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Опытные люди, посоветуйте механизм работы с кэшем. Есть серверная часть приложения. Есть база данных (база небольшая). Хочется прикрутить механизм кэширования данных. На ум приходит пара вариантов. Первый это подгрузить все данные при старте приложения, сразу их закэшировать, далее в процессе изменения данных в базе, параллельно менять данные в кэше. Второй вариант так же загрузить данные при старте, но не париться с изменением данных в кэше, а просто заново асинхронно грузить часть кэша из базы при изменении данных. Посоветуйте как лучше сделать ?

Answer (score 4):

> There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things — Phil Karlton

Решение зависит от структуры ваших данных, и от того, зачем вы используете кэш.

- Если цель - вообще избежать запросов к базе данных на чтение - то выбора у вас особо нет - вы вынуждены будете при каждом обновлении сначала менять данные в кэше, а потом уже - данные в базе.
- Если цель - просто снизить количество запросов к базе на чтение - то обычно проще просто инвалидировать кэш при изменении данных, и заново заполнять при следующей попытке чтения.

Почему второй вариант проще в реализации:

Обычно формат данных в кэше и в базе отличается (по крайней мере должен отличаться).

- В базе данные лежат в нормализованном виде - размазаны по нескольким таблицам со связями между ними.
- В кэше данные должны лежать в виде, как можно более готовом к окончательному использованию - буквально, в виде готового ответа на запрос.

Если у вас есть больше чем один способ выбрать одни и те же данные - то при каждой записи в базу вы вынуждены будете обновлять актуальными значениями несколько записей в кэше. "Париться" в этой ситуации наиболее подходящее слово :) Гораздо проще их выбросить, и доверится коду, который заполнит их при необходимости.

UP: на моем текущем проекте даже отследить, что именно надо выбросить из кэша, оказалось затруднительно.

Кроме того, внезапно оказалось, что последовательность "асинхронно выбросить, синхронно запросить новые данные" может внезапно вернуть старые значения из кэша.

В результате от идеи менять что-то или вручную выбрасывать из кэша вообще отказались, и перешли на [key-based expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774738/key-based-cache-expiration) - при изменении объекта начали не выбрасывать данные из кэша, и не записывать в кэш новые данные. А просто менять сам ключ, по которому данные для этого объекта хранятся в кэше.

Comment: а вообще, хранение всей БД в ОП(кэше) это нормально ?

Comment: @Serg более чем. правда, sql server и так физически кэширует все данные вашей базы в памяти. так что перед прикручиванием кэша стоит проверить что он даст ощутимый эффект. если запросы к sql у вас тривиальные - то кэширование может ничего и не дать.

Comment: а почему в кэше данные должны лежать в уже "готовом" виде ? если мы  будет класть готовые объекты в кэш а не сами данные, это ведь может сократить область их использования ? Например у нас есть сущность Книга с атрибутами {название, число страниц, ссылка на автора (другая сущность)}. В БД соответственно отдельно будут таблицы Авторы и Книги. Если мы в кэше будем хранить который объект Книги с автором а не отдельно авторов и отдельно книг, мы потом не сможем взять отдельно список авторов из кэша. Или тогда в кэше еще будет храниться отдельно список со всеми авторами ?

Comment: @Serg если в кэше хранить отдельно авторов и отдельно книги - то при запросе списка книг с авторами придётся как минимум джойнить две коллекции. А с этим sql справляется гораздо лучше. Гораздо проще хранить список книг+авторов и отдельно список авторов. и, например, список книг для каждого автора - кэш должен соответствовать запросам к вашему сервису. А не структуре базы данных.

Comment: @Serg и насчёт инвалидации - она иногда некритична. Например, если после смены имени автора в данных книги некоторое время будет отображаться старое значение -никто не заметит.